# Python Email sending HTML as plain text

Tags: python, email

I have the following script that is supposed to send an email; however, the email is being sent as a plain text rather than HTML.  Am I missing a piece of code?

```
import smtplib, ssl, mimetypes
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.utils import make_msgid

def send_email():    
   server = connect_server()
   if server:
   html = """\
       <html>
       <body>
       <div style="width:60%;background-color:#193048;border:4px solid #3c71aa;padding:5px 10px">                
        Putting My Email Text Here!
       </div>
       </body>
       </html>             
      """
       msg = EmailMessage()
       msg["Subject"] = "Subject"
       msg["From"] = "Support <support@example.xyz>"
       msg["To"] = "{} <{}>".format("Test Human","<test.human@somewhere.xyz>")                
       msg.set_content('Plain Text Here!')            
       msg_image = make_msgid(domain="example.xyz")        
       msg.add_alternative(html.format(msg_image=msg_image[1:-1],subtype="html"))        
       with open("./resources/email-logo.png","rb") as fp:
           maintype,subtype = mimetypes.guess_type(fp.name)[0].split('/')
           msg.get_payload()[1]add_related(fp.read(),maintype=maintype,subtype=subtype,cid=msg_image)
       server.sendmail("Support <support@example.xyz","{} <{}>".format(Test Human,test.human@somewhere.xyz),msg.as_string())
       server.quit()
```

I am using Python3.9 on Ubuntu 18.04.  Thanks All!

Answer (score 8):

I usually use the `smtplib`

In addition to set your text as a `simple text`, you need to set the `html` content too!

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Your HTML Title</title>
  <body>
   <h1>The best html email content!!!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
"""

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login('my_email', 'my_password')
    try:
        msg = EmailMessage()
        msg.set_content('simple text would go here - This is a fallback for html content')
        msg.add_alternative(html, subtype='html')
        msg['Subject'] = 'Subject of your email would go here!'
        msg['From'] = 'my_email'
        msg['To'] = 'my_contact@mail.com'
        msg['Cc'] = ''
        msg['Bcc'] = ''
        smtp.send_message(msg)
     except:
        print("Something went wrong!!!")
print("DONE!")
```

Comment: my code is, essentially, the same as yours except for the `DOCTYPE` in the HTML.  Added it but it still sends the html in plain text.

Comment: I'm using python 3.8 on windows and it works seamlessly fine!

Comment: @Elcid_91 you're probably looking at old e-mail. I just tried this example, with App Password for Gmail, and the content was in HTML indeed.

Comment: Looks like the issue was in the image.  I removed adding the image and it went over properly.  So now I can't figure out what's wrong with adding an embedded image.

Comment: Have you used `<img src="cid:{msg_image}" />` on html source ? Also your original source is missing a `.` between `msg.get_payload()[1]` and `add_related`.

Comment: So I've been trying to do the same for a few days and to me embedding images in the html is kind of tricky, consistency wise! But fortunately I found a solution that works for all of the standard email clients! Please read more about it here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534150/image-source-attribute-is-getting-encrypted-messed-up-in-the-html-part-while-try/65599679#65599679)

Comment: Yes @Mokhless I use external images too.